# Is it possible to have entries only visible to logged-in users?

Tags: entries

I want to have a public and private (logged in users) section on the front-end. Is that possible on craft?

Answer (score 8):

Yes. You need to build a [frontend login form](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/login-form) and then block non logged in users from seeing the entries with something along the lines of this:

```
{% if craft.session.isLoggedIn %}
    {# put content here #}
{% endif %}
```

You can also check if the user belongs to a specific group with `isInGroup('groupHandle')` [(more here)](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/usermodel#isInGroup)

Comment: You can also use [`{% if currentUser %}`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/global-variables#currentUser) , which will return `false` if the user is not logged in.

Comment: any difference between this and {% requireLogin %}?

Comment: `{% requireLogin %}` will redirect you to your `loginPath` if you are not logged in. [More here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/requirelogin)

Comment: Something seems to have changed. None of these seem to work anymore in Craft CMS 3.3.16.3 {% if craft.session.isLoggedIn %} or {% if currentUser %} - Mr. Sadface.

Comment: `{% if currentUser %}` should definitely still work: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/global-variables.html#currentuser  There's also the page-wide `{% requireLogin %}` tag, but that probably doesn't prevent the entry from showing up on listing pages.